How to chain operations in pandas entirely in-line?
I often want to both manipulate and display a dataframe during a sequence of chained operations, for which I would use*:
df = (
  df

  #Modify the dataframe:
  .assign(new_column=...)

  #View result (without killing the chain)
  .pipe(lambda df_: display(df_) or df_)

  #...further chaining is possible
)

The code block above adds new_column to the dataframe, displays the new dataframe, and finally returns it. Chaining works here because display returns a falsy value (None).
My question is about scenarios where I want to replace display with plt.plot or some function that returns a truthy value. In such cases, df_ would no longer propagate through the chain.
Currently, my round this is to define an external function transparent_pipe that can run plt.plot or any other method(s), whilst also ensuring that the dataframe gets propagated:
def transparent_pipe(df, *funcs):
  [func(df) for func in funcs]
  return df

df = (
  df

  #Modify the dataframe:
  .assign(new_column=...)

  #Visualise a column from the modified df, without killing the chain
  .pipe(lambda df_: transparent_pipe(df_, plt.ecdf(df_.new_column), display(df_), ...)

  #...further chaining is possible
)

Question
Is there an entirely in-line way of doing this, without needing to define transparent_pipe?
Preferably just using pandas.

*Tip from Effective Pandas 2: Opinionated Patterns for Data Manipulation, M. Harrison, 2024.

With pyjanitor, you could use also:
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

df = (pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
        .also(display)
        .mul(10)
     )

Alternatively, with a wrapper function to hide the output of any function and replace it by its first parameter (=the DataFrame):
def hide(f):
    """The inner function should accept the DataFrame as first parameter"""
    def inner(df, *args, **kwargs):
        f(df, *args, **kwargs)
        return df
    return inner

df = (pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
        .pipe(hide(display))
        .mul(10)
     )

Or, going like the original approach with short-circuiting:
df = (pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
        .pipe(lambda x: plt.ecdf(x['col1']) and False or x) # truthy output
        .pipe(lambda x: display(x['col1']) and False or x)  # falsy output
        .mul(10)
     )

Or forcing a truthy with a tuple:
df = (pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': [4, 5, 6]})
        # example 1
        .pipe(lambda x: (display(x),) and x)
        # example 2
        .pipe(lambda x: (display(x), plt.ecdf(x['col1'])) and x)
        .mul(10)
     )


Thanks for your contribution. I prefer a solution that just uses pandas. hide is a nice alternative to my transparent_pipe, but my objective is to avoid having to define such helper functions.

@MuhammedYunus if you want something like lambda df_: display(df_) or df_, then check the third approach ;)

@MuhammedYunus I'm not sure I follow, you want to run many functions? I think x or ... would fail since a DataFrame cannot be converted to boolean. I provided yet another improvement ;)

You're right, I meant .pipe(lambda x: funcA(x) and funcB(x) and ... and False or x). I like the new suggestion

You could instead compose a list inside the .pipe() operation, and then extract the dataframe from that list: .pipe(lambda x: [x, funcA(x), funcB(x), ...][0])
df = (
  df

  #Modify the dataframe:
  .assign(new_column=...)

  #Various visualisations, without killing the chain
  .pipe(lambda df_: [display(df_), plt.ecdf(df_.new_column), ..., df_)[-1]

  #...further chaining is possible
)

This allows you to define and run arbitrary operations in-line, whilst also ensuring that the modified dataframe will be propagated along.

I have selected the answer by @mozway in preference to this answer, although they are quite similar.
The fourth suggestion by @mozway is:
.pipe(lambda x: (funcA(x), funcB(x), ...) and x)

I prefer it over mine because there's no need to index out the dataframe, which gets returned automatically via truthy evaluation.
